# How to improve the confidence score of the intent in Rasa NLU?

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I was working on Rasa NLU for intent classification, in [link](http://rasa.com/docs/nlu/master/quickstart/) how shall I improve the confidence score for a given intent.

I have tried to give more training data but still the confidence score isn't increasing. Can anyone please let me know which parameters \ hyperparameters I can tune in order to get good confidence score.
I did tried to all possible combinations provided in this [link](http://rasa.com/docs/nlu/master/choosing_pipeline/#choosing-pipeline) but still there was hardly any improvement.

I did checked the suggestion provided over here, but I am looking for granular tuning of the model such that it can perform better.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**: Please provide a valid reason for down-voting the question.

Comment: Is your training data proprietary or can you share it? How many intents/training examples per intent? which pipeline? How similar are your intents? Do you have entities? I don't feel like you've provided enough information to get more of an answer than just: provide more training data.

Comment: Sorry couldn't able to share the training data, Intents is around 44 and training distinct examples are around 1k per intent.

Comment: Sounds way over fit. As in way too many training examples per intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tensorflow_embedding which gives confidence score near to .9, rather than using spacy_sklearn which provides neat to .3

Answer (score 0):

Depending whether spaCy provides a good [language model](https://spacy.io/usage/models) for your language, you should either use the spaCy [pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/#choosing-a-rasa-nlu-pipeline) (as it comes with pretrained models) or the `tensorflow_embedding` [pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/#choosing-a-rasa-nlu-pipeline) which works with any language but requires more training examples.

I think that your problems might be caused by overlapping training examples. An example to clarify:

```
## intent:ask_bot_name
- Tell me your name
- What is your name
- name please

## intent:ask_location_name
- Tell me the name
- What's the name
- name please
```

So I would suggest to go through your training data and have a look whether different intents have the same or very very similar examples.